# Java TCP Socket not timing out (called in a Servlet)

Tags: java, sockets, servlets, tcp

Good Day,

I have a Java Servlet where I actually need to send a TCP Packet. If the connection is opened, I can send the data successfully..

However, if it does need to timeout, it never does.

My socket sending code looks like this:

```
private static String sendMessage(int command,String data,int port,String ip){
    try{
        String sendString=Integer.toString(command)+":"+data+'$'+'\n';
        BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        Socket clientSocket = new Socket(ip, port);
        clientSocket.setSoTimeout(30000);
        DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        outToServer.writeBytes(sendString);
        String rcvString = inFromServer.readLine();
        System.out.println("FROM DEVICE: " + rcvString);
        clientSocket.close();
        return rcvString;
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

As you can see, I set the timeout to 30s. However, it takes almost 80s to timeout. Sometimes it takes 60s. It keeps varying. I set the timeout to 10s and it still takes as long. It's as if that function is not working at all. What gives!? Is it a threading issue?

Comment: because servlet calls happen in a thread/threadpool. Could that be the issue? I need to make a TCP call inside a servlet! The above code calls directly in the servlet.

Comment: The SO_TIMEOUT is relevant when reading from the socket. Although it is not clear, you seem to assume that the timeout is relevant when connecting the socket. It is not. If you want to specify a timeout for the TCP connect, you should read the documentation for the Socket class, which will tell you how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the timeout after the connect.

Try this:

```
 private static String sendMessage(int command,String data,int port,String ip){
     try{
         String sendString=Integer.toString(command)+":"+data+'$'+'\n';
         BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(System.in));

         // Socket clientSocket = new Socket(ip, port);
         // clientSocket.setSoTimeout(30000);

         Socket clientSocket = new Socket();
         InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName(ip);
         SocketAddress sockaddr = new InetSocketAddress(addr, port);
         clientSocket.connect(sockaddr, 20000); // 20 seconds time out

         DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
         BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
         outToServer.writeBytes(sendString);
         String rcvString = inFromServer.readLine();
         System.out.println("FROM DEVICE: " + rcvString);
         clientSocket.close();
         return rcvString;
     }catch(Exception e){
         System.err.println(e.getMessage());
     }

     return NULL;
 }
```

Comment: He is setting a read timeout after the connect. Nothing wrong with that, but it's a read timeout, not a connect timeout. This code uses a connect timeout but omits the read timeout altogether.